# nginx, django -- uwsgi does not see POST data

Tags: python, django, nginx, uwsgi

Here is the .ini file:

```
module=myapp.wsgi:application
master=True
pidfile=/tmp/project-master.pid
socket=127.0.0.1:8000
vacuum=True
max-requests=5000
daemonize=/home/mercier/django/site/wsgi.log
buffer-size=327680
processes=16
listen=500
timeout=10
post-buffering=1
```

nginx forwards the connection using uwsgi_pass directive.

No post data is seen from django - the request.POST is just {}. This is a huge problem... How can I fix this? Post data was seen in the development (runserver).

Important note: both nginx and wsgi respond with 200 (OK). I also tried to set different post-bufferings (as found here and there), but no difference...

django 1.4
uwsgi 1.9.15
nginx 1.2.1

EDIT3:
Now I try to use webob: (load request.environ)
The client disconnected while sending the POST/PUT body (39 more bytes were expected)

Now I try manually: print request.environ['wsgi.input'].read(39) -> is an empty line...

Edit4: by not I tried just about any hint I found on the net, I'm considering trying fcgi or deploying it on a runserver ;(

Edit5: relevant nginx.conf (enabled site) section:

```
server {

        listen   80; 

        server_name  localhost;

        access_log  /var/log/nginx/localhost.access.log;


        location / {
                root   /var/www;
                index  index.html index.htm;
                proxy_set_header X-FORWARDED-FOR $remote_addr;

                include uwsgi_params;
                uwsgi_pass_request_body on;
                uwsgi_pass_request_headers on;
                uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8000;



        }
```

uwsgi_params:

```
uwsgi_param     QUERY_STRING            $query_string;
uwsgi_param     REQUEST_METHOD          $request_method;
uwsgi_param     CONTENT_TYPE            $content_type;
uwsgi_param     CONTENT_LENGTH          $content_length;

uwsgi_param     REQUEST_URI             $request_uri;
uwsgi_param     PATH_INFO               $document_uri;
uwsgi_param     DOCUMENT_ROOT           $document_root;
uwsgi_param     SERVER_PROTOCOL         $server_protocol;
uwsgi_param     UWSGI_SCHEME            $scheme;

uwsgi_param     REMOTE_ADDR             $remote_addr;
uwsgi_param     REMOTE_PORT             $remote_port;
uwsgi_param     SERVER_PORT             $server_port;
uwsgi_param     SERVER_NAME             $server_name;
uwsgi_param     DOCUMENT_BODY           $request_body;
```

Edit6:

This is the application (module=) I'm using:

```
import os,sys
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "site.settings")
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),
"../../")))
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),
"../")))

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Comment: Note: $request_body is my workaround for this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

x=request.body

This should be the first line in any django app ran by wsgi. Then POST DATA works. Django just must read the body of request immediately if it is used later.

However, there still is this problem:
invalid uwsgi request (current strsize: 16705). skip.

So I it is difficult to use uwsgi in this setting. I solved this by the use of fcgi, which does not have such limits.

Justification: strsize is not configurable -- http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.wsgi.uwsgi.general/5712

Edit: Roberto is right -- strsize is unrelated to request's body and it WORKS even in uwsgi. Debugging a problem during travelling, nights etc is not always a good idea ;)
However, Django must read the body request immediately and this is beyond doubt. The request's body must be read prior doing anything else.

Comment: do not do it, you are passing the whole body (that can be huge) as a single CGI var (that has limited size). There is nothing magic to pass request body, so i suppose you are doing something wrong. As i have already suggested try removing nginx and use only uWSGI to see where the problem is

Comment: I did as you suggested and uwsgi still does not see any POST data. It does see content length, the same is with content_length from nginx since it is explicitly passed as uwsgi_param. The body (i.e. POST data) is not, so the only possible solution is to pass the whole body, is that correct?

Comment: But what can I do wrong? I paid attention to what is in docs/tutorials/howtos on the net... Ini is above, nginx has a rather standard conf. what is the max size of a uwsgi_param? You say it is limited.

Comment: btw, the "basic test" from https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi-docs/blob/master/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.rst appears to be working when sending POST data. But a real configuration with django does not ;/

Comment: You are right. uWSGI's vars are limited by 16705. Now that's a problem because otherwise it is impossible to read post data. Something is wrong but it seems I can't find this problem though I think I tried virtually everything (original post updated).

Comment: double check if you have some third-party middleware making mess with wsgi.input (like custom file upload handlers), eventually run with single process and strace it in http-socket mode (so you can see what is happening low-level)

Comment: btw, isn't it weird that even if I do a .read() on wsgi.input it outputs nothing? content_length is of course set.

Comment: stop embedding the body in the cgi vars, is wrong.If you cannot fix the problem but you can use fastcgi i see no problems but saying uwsgi is unusable in production because it limits a completely wrong behaviour is unfair

Answer (score 1):

Try removing nginx to see where the problem is. Run uWSGI in http mode:

http-socket=127.0.0.1:8000

and connect to port 8000

if all works, ensure nginx is passing the CONTENT_LENGTH parameter

Eventually paste your nginx config

Comment: See my latest edit of a post. Django is the only cause, however, your suggestions were indispensable. Thanks.

Comment: for nginx to pass POST body through uwsgi protocol CONTENT_LENGTH uwsgi_param is essential. It wasn't very obvious - thank you.